# How to import package.json into Typescript file without including it in the compiled output?

Tags: json, typescript, package.json

Using Typescript 2.9 I am able to successfully import the local package.json file and use the values. However I now have the issue where the package.json file is included in the compiled output, when I just want the resulting JS files to use the actual package.json.

My package has the following files:

```
src/
  index.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

My index.ts imports the package.json:

```
import pkg = require("../package.json");
```

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Ideally the result would be:

```
lib/
  index.js
package.json
```

However what I actually get is:

```
lib/
  src/
    index.js
  package.json
package.json
```

Comment: The accepted answer became untrue the month after it was written. There are two working solutions below, and one of them should be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I just want the resulting JS files to use the actual package.json.

Your `lib` will always be a *straight copy* if the structure of your src files. If you include `package.json` into the TypeScript compilation context then it will change your lib to `package.json + src`.

> How to import package.json into Typescript file without including it in the compiled output?

You can't if you *import* it.

## Alternative

Have *two* projects, as mentioned by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61468012/390330

Comment: darn okay I thought this might be the case. for anyone else confused by this, I solved it by manually bringing in the json file using the fs module and `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: This answer is not true (at least for newer TypeScript versions). Look at my answer below which has the solution.

Comment: @Dominik How is it not true? You can't ***`import`*** it. Your solution uses `require`. But now, in even ***newer*** code, your solution won't work because everyone is moving to ESM.

Comment: @Inigo you are right. I said that because of the statement in this answer "You can't if you import it." while the questioner was using 'require' in their question. I treated 'require' as a way of import (and I still think it is technically).

Comment: @Dominik understood. The key thing to notice is that in this answer baserat italicized the word "import"...  He was emphasizing the distinction.

Comment: @Inigo yeah, right. I was not paying attention to the italicization. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 7):

> [This approach won't work for ESM targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070138/how-to-import-package-json-into-typescript-file-without-including-it-in-the-comp/61468012#comment114812947_57934516). If you trying to create an ES6 Module, you'll have to use a different solution.

I am using TypeScript 3.5.1 and if I import the package.json with the `require()` function then it is not copied over to the compile output so the output looks like your ideal result.

My tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "downlevelIteration": true
    "outDir": "./ts-out",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false
  },
  "include": [
    "./src"
  ]
}
```

And I just import it like this:

```js
const pkg = require('../package.json');
```

I have found this solution in Facebook's Jest framework source code (they are using Lerna + TypeScript): https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-core/src/version.ts

Comment: It works if your target module system is `commonjs`. However, it will produce an invalid ESM output which contains CommonJS require expression if your `module` is `ES6`/`ESNext`.

Answer (score 6):

You want a few somewhat contradictory things:

1. You want to import `package.json`, meaning you are treating it as source
2. But you don't want it to be compiled/emitted to the `outDir` as is done for source
3. You don't want the output path within outDir to include "src/", which is what happens when you make `rootDir` point to the project root rather than the `src` root, which is the only way you can get the import statement to work.

### solution: *use separate Typescript sub-projects*

These contradictions won't be contradictions if you logically break your project into separate sub-projects. You will need Typescript 3's new [Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#overall-structure) feature.

We'll treat the `src` directory and the root directory containing `package.json` as separate projects. Each will have its own `tsconfig` file:

1. Give the `src` dir its own project.

   **`./src/tsconfig.json`**:

   ```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": ".",
        "outDir": "../lib/",
        "resolveJsonModule": true
      },
      "references": [      // this is how we declare a dependency from
        { "path": "../" }  // this project to the one at the root dir`
      ]
    }
   ```
2. Give the root dir its own project.

   **`./tsconfig.json`**:

   ```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": ".",
        "outDir": ".",  // if out path for a file is same as its src path, nothing will be emitted
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "composite": true  // required on the dependency project for references to work
      },
      "files": [         // by whitelisting the files to include, TS won't automatically
        "package.json"   // include all source below root, which is the default.
      ]
    }
   ```

   Because for the root sub-project's output is the self-same directory, and because the source path and output path for `package.json` end up the same, `tsc` won't do anything.... effectively a no-op.
3. run `tsc --build src` and voilà!  The result will be:

   ```
    lib/
      index.js
    package.json
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `compilerOptions.moduleResolution`, `compilerOptions.resolveJsonModule` and `include` like below.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
    // ...
  },
  "include": [
    "./src",
    "package.json"
  ]
}
```

Then run `$ tsc -b` inside the folder where the tsconfig.json file is, assuming that the `package.json` file is on the same path as `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score -3):

set the `rootDir`option inside your `tsconfig` as shown below

```
"compilerOptions": {    
    "rootDir": "./src"         
}`
```

Comment: This doesn't really makes sense. if he wants to import the package.json, he will have an issue by doing what you say. TypeScript will complain that he is trying to import files that are outside the rootDir, and that perfectly makes sense.